# Nginx add headers and proxy_pass for CORS bypass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cors

I want to make CORS site with API on proxy_pass server. But

```
location / {

     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204; break;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }



  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass       http://api:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

returns 405 from upstream. Without proxy_pass this snippet works as expected.

How to break and return 204?

Comment: Where did you get 405? What url? What in the logs?

Comment: I get 405 from upstream, but i want 204 from nginx and not to call proxy for OPTIONS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ifs` not works for sublocations. Nginx parses locations first and run it without parsing parent`s code.

`proxy_pass` not working inside `if`. But it needed to be duplicated on each locations.

So i can move `if` inside sublocation.

```
server {
  listen 8080 default_server;
  listen [::]:8080 default_server;
  server_name _;

  location /api/ {

       if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204; break;
     }

     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }

    proxy_pass       http://api:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
...
}
```